# Can Software keyloggers be able to track virtual keyboard entries

Tags: keyloggers

In some online banking sites, they provide a virtual onscreen keyboard(the keys will be shifted randomly when each time you open it. Not in the QWERTY order).

If we use such keyboard, any keylogger application can log/capture the keys clicked.

Assume The input element for username and password is not accessible.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but here, the keys are arranged randomly. In QWERTY virtual keyboard, it can be done. But I would like to know this specific  case

Comment: This case is actually covered in the question I've linked too. And it is also covered by screen recording since both mouse position AND screen content gets recorded.

Comment: OS-based key capture should not work if the web keyboard is made correctly, but screen-shot software might be able to read any visual feedback such a keyboard produces, as well as the mouse/touch coords; info which might be enough to decode the password entry.